# itoa function for GCC

Tags: c

`itoa` is not an ANSI-C standard therefore doesn't work for GCC

```
char* itoa(int val, int base){
    static char buf[32] = {0};
    int i = 30;
    for(; val && i ; --i, val /= base)
        buf[i] = "0123456789abcdef"[val % base];
    return &buf[i+1];

}
```

Questions I have

1. `static char buf[32]`
    Why use static? Can I delete that?
2. Why `i=30`?
   Shouldn't it be 31? 0 to 31 for 32 bits.
3. For the for-loop, what is `val /= base` trying to do?
4. Inside the for-loop, what does `val%base` do? I know it's for remainder but how's that relate to here? What's the difference between `val/base` versus `val%base`?

Comment: You could use `snprintf` instead, sounds simpler and safer.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour And `sprintf` is also thread-safe, which `itoa` is not nor ever will be.

Comment: If you can use `snprintf`, don't use `sprintf`.

Comment: Hello.. I am trying to learn here.  inside logic.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf It's easy enough to prevent buffer overflows with `sprintf`. The only risks are when you have no idea what you're doing or laziness.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf The original comment posted by Shafik mentioned `sprintf`, so I was simply replying to him.  His comment has since been edited.  Please don't react so strongly based on your own assumptions, it is rather rude and completely unnecessary.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf Using `sprintf` is fine in controlled situations. In this particular code, as long as the output array is sized to contain the output of the conversion of any possible input (which it seems to be), it should be fine. It's when you don't have control over the input and can't prove that it is safe that you don't want to use it. There are other issues in this code that need more attention than `sprintf` (e.g. what happens when you call it with 1,000,000, and then call it again with 42?).

Comment: @twalberg yes lets only use ``sprintf`` in controlled situations. because humans don't have habits and bad code doesn't exist due to magic fairies. have fun with your vulnerable code :)

Comment: There is NOTHING wrong with this question.

Comment: @JackCColeman mmm I don't fully agree. It's a set of questions. 'what is `val /= base` trying to do?' Well, IT DOESN'T try to do anything. It _does_ what it says on the tin. It divides val by base. Anyways, I get high "doesn't show minimal understanding" vibes here. I'd just leave the question be, but I understand the off-topic voters. I mean, I can come up with so many code snippets I would like people to explain for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) as @Blastfurnace noted, the static is needed so that the buffer still exists when the function returns

2) i=30 because its the last used index, because the index 31 needs to be NULL (\0). because c works with Null-Terminated-Strings

3) removing the last digit. i.e: val = 12345, base = 10, val / base = 1234, 5 is removed

4) getting the current digit (right to left) , 12345 % 10 = 5 (its also the index of the char array representing the digits (very efficient)

Comment: It would be worth noting in #1 that a static buffer means that `itoa()` is inherently not thread-safe, and cannot be used reliably in multi-threaded programs since the buffer is shared between all threads.

Comment: The `static` keyword isn't there for performance, without it the function would be returning the address of a __temporary local object__.

Comment: @x4rf41,  since question both 3 &4, you have 5 coming out first , so it's same,    so either both can implement val/base or both can do val %base since the result is same.

Comment: @lilzz 12345 / 10 = 1234 => 5 is removed. but not the result. 12345 % 10 = 5 => the digit that is put into the string. every iteration the last digit is put into the string, from right to left, and then it is removed

Answer (score 1):

1)static char buf[32]
why use static? can I delete that?

So it doesn't get reloaded everytime the routine is called.  No, the routine needs it to store the ascii values to be output.

2)why i=30?
shouldn't be 31? 0 to 31 for 32 bits
Not sure, but 30 characters represents 120 bits, not 30.

3) for the for loop, what does val /=base trying to do?
It's reducing the base on each iteration so the remainder value (used as an index to the array) will be correct.

4)inside the for loop, what does val%base do? I know it's for remainder but how's that relate to here? what's the difference between val/base versus val%base?
It calculates the remainder as an index into buf, to select the correct ascii value.  / returns the integer (rounded off) divide, not the remainder of that divide.

Value =  (Value/divisor)*divisor + Value%divisor.

thanks